# What is the value of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\left(\log\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)^2}{x^2+1}\right)\right)$

Tags: limits

What is value of the limit given by $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\log\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)^2}{x^2+1}\right)\right)$?

I substituted $x$ by $\infty$ so I got this form $\displaystyle\log \left(\frac{(\infty - 1)^2}{\infty^2 + 1} \right)$. Is this form equal to $\displaystyle \log\left(\frac{\infty^2}{\infty^2}\right) = \log \left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right)^2 = 2\log\left(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\right)$? What are the following steps?

Comment: First of all I would multiply out the square: $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$. Then dividing the numerator and the denominator by $x^2$

Comment: As a note, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is called an indeterminate form, which means that you can't calculate it. If you see one, you need to modify your expression somehow to remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\log\left(\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^+1}\right)=\log\left(1-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1}\right)$$

But
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2 x}{x^2+1}=0$$

so that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{2 x}{x^2+1}\right)=\log(1+0)=\log(1)=0$$

Comment: I don't understand the final step, why $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{-2 x}{x^2+1}\right)$=0

Comment: The composition of continuous function is continuous. Since $\log(x)$ is continuous in a neighborhood around $1$, we can "move the limit" into the natural log to get that it is just $\log(1+0)$.

Comment: @Mario Sorry, but $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{-2 x}{x^2+1}\right)=\color{red}{-\infty}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(x-1)^{2}}{x^{2}+1}=\dfrac{x^{2}-2x+1}{x^{2}+1}\rightarrow 1,
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\ln\dfrac{(x-1)^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\rightarrow\ln 1=0.
\end{align*}